# How can I make an AJAX request and then remove the iframe the request was made from?

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Background:**

On my page there is an option to upload files, this opens an iframe that contains a form for uploading files. If the user decides to cancel the upload I want to make sure any files that were uploaded get deleted. So I make an ajax call to a jsp that runs a function to delete any temp files that were uploaded. After making the ajax call I remove the iframe from the screen so the user can continue their work. The jsp that deletes the files doesn't return anything and I don't need to let the user know that temp files were deleted.

I found that this runs fine in IE but in chrome and safari an error is displayed to the user, after debugging for a while I found that the cause for the error was that the ajax call returns after the iframe is removed and chrome and safari don't like returning an ajax call to a removed iframe. So one solution is to make the ajax call synchronous. Another solution is to make the jsp spawn a thread to manage the delete.

**Question:**

*What I'm wondering is if there is some way to modify the ajax call so it will return to a different page than the one that's getting removed?*

```
function cancelAndDelete()
{
    $.ajax({url:"removeTempFiles.jsp", data: {id: fileId}, async: true});
    $("#iframe").remove();
}
```

Something like $(window.opener).ajax() doesn't seem to work but that's the idea I'm going for.

Comment: Have the content inside the iframe remove the iframe. `window.parent.$("#iframe").remove()`

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cancelAndDelete()
{
    $.ajax({url:"removeTempFiles.jsp", data: {id: fileId}, async: true}, complete: window.location.replace("http://URL HERE.com"));
    $("#iframe").remove();
}
```

Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: window.location.replace will get executed too early

Comment: ya, you have to wrap it inside an anonymous function

Comment: It doesn't sound like it would do what I want. The page doesn't need to reload, I just need the iframe that pops up on the page to go away, which is what the .remove() is doing. It's just doing it too soon.